# Control reaches end of non void function in bool function

Tags: c++

This is the bit of code that I'm currently working on and I can't seem to figure out a way to make this function stop throwing the "control reaches end of non-void function" error. Shouldn't the else statement catch anything the if statement doesn't and return either true or false?

```
bool operator == (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y)
{
    if (x.currentSize != y.currentSize)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.currentSize; i++)
        {
                if (x.integer[i] != y.integer[i])
                {
                    return false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if both `x.currentSize` and `y.currentSize` are zero?

Comment: You've got some unreachable code there. You'll never actually get to that break statement.

Comment: `} // <<<<<<<<<<<< ************* !!!!!!`  at the end simply??? What do you not understand from that warning/error message please? put `return false; }` or  `return true; }` instead. I don't know what's your actual use case is (TL;DR;).

Comment: Also note `break;` is redundant after `return false;`.

Answer (score 4):

If `x.currentsize == 0` and `y.currentsize == 0`, then you will never reach a `return` statement.

I get the feeling that you intended to write the following code. Note that we only `return true` once we've tested the whole list.

```
bool operator==(const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y)
{
    if (x.currentSize != y.currentSize)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.currentSize; i++)
        if (x.integer[i] != y.integer[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @user4815162342 Whoops. you're right.

Answer (score 2):

You must put a return on the first `else`, in case your method doesn't go through the for loop, for example, when `x.currentSize = 0`

Also, your `if` condition always returns a value after the first iteration, so you should change it like this, so you can check all elements in the `Array`

```
bool operator == (const MyInt& x, const MyInt& y)
{
    if (x.currentSize != y.currentSize)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.currentSize; i++)
                if (x.integer[i] != y.integer[i])
                    return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the for loop will never test `x.integer[1] != y.integer[1]` because we've already broken out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The general reason of such errors is a bad code that is difficult to read.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
bool operator ==( const MyInt &x, const MyInt &y )
{
    if ( x.currentSize == y.currentSize )
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (  i < x.currentSize && x.integer[i] == y.integer[i] ) i++;

        return ( i == x.currentSize );
    }

    return ( false );
}
```

Or if `integer` is a pointer or an array then you could apply standard algorithm `std::equal` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...
bool operator ==( const MyInt &x, const MyInt &y )
{
    return ( x.currentSize == y.currentSize && 
             std::equal( x.integer, x.integer + x.currentSize, y.integer ) );
}
```

I think this code looks much better does not it?

Comment: No, it does not look better. Replace the outer `else` clause with the `return false;` statement.  By the way, the `return` is not a function and therefore the parenthesis are not necessary.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews It does look much better. Of course the else can be removed but it is a matter of taste. As for return then fot example if statement also is not a function and catch is not a function. The adea that after return there is an expression and it is a good idea to separate keyword return from the expression.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews  I removed else statement.:)